# Is it possible to use functions from a "false parent" class, that have the current class as a property?

Tags: php, class, oop

The following example defines a foo class, which constructs a bar class, and stores it as a property `$foo->bar`. In the bar class, is it possible to reference the 'false' parent class, and use it's functions?

```
class bar
{
    public function test_false_parent()
    {
            //Is it possible to access foo->display() from here
        {unknown code}::display();
    }
}

class foo
{
    public $bar;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->bar = new bar;
    }

    public function display()
    {
        echo "in";
    }
}

$foo = new foo;

$foo->bar->test_false_parent();
//Equivalent to $foo->display();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not without a back reference:

```
class bar
{
    protected $foo;

    public function __construct(foo $foo)
    {
        $this->foo = $foo;
    }

    public function test_false_parent()
    {
        $this->foo->display();
    }
}

class foo
{
    public $bar;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->bar = new bar($this);
    }

    public function display()
    {
        echo "in";
    }
}

$foo = new foo;

$foo->bar->test_false_parent();
```

Comment: Awesome solution because you can do `$foo->bar->foo->bar->foo->bar->foo->bar->test_false_parent()` :)

Comment: Ha, just had the same thought. Thanks a lot! I'm not sure I'm going to use this approach, but it's good to know as a possibility.